# Is there any way to forward mail from the command line in Linux

Tags: command-line, email, forwarding

I'm looking at the mail command which fires off Heirloom Mail.
My procmail failed and it has 55 messages in the queue. 
I need to forward them out to another email and then process them manually. 
I'm not sure how to get them from the Linux server out to my email though.

Comment: Hi there....I discovered that I had to "set forward-as-attachment" then I could forward out the mail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that I had to "set forward-as-attachment" then I could forward out the mail...

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do the same. Could you give an example of the exact command that would be used, for example, if I wanted to forward the e-mail at position 5 to example@example.com ?